# Serial expansion of inverse function of $\frac{x}{\ln x}$

Tags: prime-numbers, taylor-expansion, inverse-function

Since $G(x)=\frac{x}{\ln x}$ is asymptotical equivalent with the prime counting function $\pi(x)$, the inverse $G^{-1}(n)$ must be asymptotical equivalent with the prime number function $p_n$.

$x=G^{-1}(n)$ can be calculated for $n\geq 3$ by 
$x=\underset{k\to\infty}{\lim}x_k$, where $x_{k+1}=n\cdot\ln x_k$ where 
$x_0=3$, but I would like to have the serial expansion anyway.

---

In fact, $\; n\ln n<p_n<G^{-1}(n)\;$ and the mean $f(n)=\frac{n\ln n+G^{-1}(n)}{2}$ follows $p_n$ rather well.
Down $p_n$ is blue and $f(n)$ is red:
[image]

Comment: The result you get is $p_n \sim n \log n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: But $G^{-1}(n)\neq n\ln n$ and also $G^{-1}(n)\sim p_n$.

Comment: That's not a contradiction; we have $G^{-1}(n) \sim n \log n$ too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). But for any branch of the inverse the radius of convergence of the series will be finite, unusable for any asymptotical reasoning.